# How to correctly stop and restart threads, while inside the thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, queue

I am running a SpringBoot application that has business service which continuously triggers a method which populates a global queue with its messages. Inside this method, as it is triggered more than 15-30 times a second, the method checks a global array of boolean values to ensure a thread of a specific index is not started (0-7). If the thread is not started, the method triggers the thread. Each thread is responsible for reading from the global queue of messages and performing a task on this message. However, I notice that as the application runs longer, I only see one of those single threads running the operation whilst the others are stuck.

My question is, if I have:

```
public static void onMessage(String record) {
     global.add(record);
     if(threads[0] == false) {
     threads[0] = true;
     thread0.start() // Name of the thread index included in runnable
> }
```

Basically the above is constantly triggered, populates the queue, tries to start the thread and that is it.

Then I have:

```
public void run() { 
    String recordToUse;
    int thread_num = Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    long startThreadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endThreadTime = startThreadTime + 60 * 1000; // Run the thread for 1 minute.
                
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endThreadTime) {
        if(!global.isEmpty()) {
            recordToUse = global.remove();
            System.out.println("Successful removal: Thread-"+ thread_num);
        } else {
            continue; // If the queue is empty, keep checking until it is not empty. 
        }
        // Then we have more operations that work on the message
    }
    threads[thread_num] = false; // Mark that this thread is now finished and the onMessage method knows it can start another thread.
    return;
}
```

The runnable implementation takes a number as an argument basically to just store the number of the thread inside the thread, so we have something like **Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable,"0");** so that the above thread knows that it is number 0 index.

After the application runs as intended, I see that at first out of the 8 intended threads, at first it runs fine and displays messages like:

```
Successful removal: Thread-2
Successful removal: Thread-0
Successful removal: Thread-5
Successful removal: Thread-7
Successful removal: Thread-4
Successful removal: Thread-1
```

But after like 5-10 minutes, it focuses on a **single** thread. I only see messages like:

```
Successful removal: Thread-6
Successful removal: Thread-6
Successful removal: Thread-6
Successful removal: Thread-6
Successful removal: Thread-6
Successful removal: Thread-6
```

I am not exactly sure what is happening, and some guidance would be great! My idea is that the thread is accessing a synchronized method and the other threads are all waiting for it, but I am not sure that would be the case since they all work initially.

Thanks.

I have been trying to sleep the threads here and there, I have been playing with the continue part of the thread, but I cannot see where these threads are stuck.

Comment: This seems very complex so I have to ask: Why do you want to control the threads yourself? Could you just use a thread pool and leave the handling to Spring/Java?

Comment: Seems like you are needlessly reinventing `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Would using ExecutorService work in this scenario? In a way, onMessage behaves as a main method here, it is executed repeatedly. I want to populate the queue with the messages that it gets, but I do not want onMessage to create increasingly more and more threads as it runs. The general idea is to keep the threads alive for more than a single message in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a concurrent, blocking queue. (See `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`.)
2. Keep adding your items to that queue, without worrying at all who reads them, when they read them, if they read them.
3. Create N threads where each thread just runs without letting anyone know whether it is busy or not.
4. Each thread runs a loop which reads the next item from the queue and processes it. To read the next item from the queue, use the blocking dequeue method, so that the thread will be blocked waiting until an item is available.
5. When you want the threads to quit, enqueue N instances of a special sentinel value which means "please quit". Each queue checks for that value, and quits.
6. ***You are done.***

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! However, I am curious about one scenario. When two threads get to the point of dequeue from a blocking queue of a single item, one thread will dequeue successfully--how can I prevent the Empty Stack/Queue Exception from being thrown when the second thread proceeds to pull from the blocking queue after the first finishes? @MikeNakis

Comment: @FilipKlosiewicz It is part of BlockingQueue's **raison d'être** to take care of precisely this.  When 5 threads are blocked waiting to dequeue an item, and an item arrives, one of them will receive the item. The other 4 will just stay waiting. They will never know that an item was enqueued and it was picked up by another thread.

Comment: There are many examples on the interwebz, this one perhaps being one of the best: https://mkyong.com/java/java-blockingqueue-examples/